# How do I get `ArrayMesh` to reverse the order of data in a 3D array?

Tags: plotting, bugs, mesh, list-manipulation

The following array has non-zero entries in the cells where all three indices are equal:

```
foo = SparseArray[{i_, i_, i_} -> 1, {4, 4, 4}]
```

When I try to render this in `ArrayMesh`, though, the resulting graphic has the third axis reversed:

```
ArrayMesh[foo, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AxesLabel -> {i, j, k}]
```

[image]

The filled cells should be on the diagonal going from the lower left to the upper right.

Using the `DataReversed -> True` option appears to reverse the first axis only (or equivalently, the second and third axes while leaving the first axis the same):

```
ArrayMesh[foo, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", DataReversed -> True, AxesLabel -> {i, j, k}]
```

[image]

Trying to set an option such as `DataReversed -> {True, False}` or `DataReversed -> {True, False, True}` results in a graph identical to the first graph.

Is there a way to get Mathematica to render all three axes in the correct order?  I am using MM 12.0.0 on a Mac, in case this is version-dependent.

Comment: Please send a report to Support.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed an annoyance. Apparently, vector-valued settings for `DataReversed` are just ignored. Something for support, I guess.

Does

```
ArrayMesh[Map[Reverse, foo, 1], PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AxesLabel -> {i, j, k}]
```

do what you want?

Comment: I would use `Reverse[foo, 2]` instead of `Map[Reverse, foo, 1]` myself.